# Beginner C++ Array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new to C++. Below is code to input and display an array -- a simple thing to understand how things work.

```
int main() {
  int N, i;
  int A[N];
  cin >> N;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    cin >> A[i];
  }
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    cout << A[i];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The input is:

```
4
1 2 3 4
```

and output is:

```
12
```

I have corrected my code to:

```
int N, i;
cin >> N;
int A[N];
```

This correctly displays the array.

What exactly happened? Should N have a value before initializing A[N]? But then why didn't my initial code work? Is this something to do with Hierarchy? If so, how can I get my priorities right?

If N is initialized as a large value, N has an input of specific number next, if so how come even if N=9, the output remains same: 12?

Comment: `int A[N];` declaration is using an uninitialized value.  Code statements are interpreted by the compiler in the order they are written.  And actually, variable-length arrays (like you're using here) are not a standard language feature in C++, so don't get too comfy using them.  Consider `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Note also that even after `cin >> N;` there is no guarantee that `N` is initialized.  If the user types "four", then the input will fail and stream will enter an error state.  Obviously for a throw-away program like this, it's not critical to test.  But in general you should always remember this any time you're performing formatted reads from a stream.

Comment: The statements are executed in sequence, if that's what you are wondering about. Uninitialized `N` has some actual value, that could be a very large number, this will waste a lot of memory (I don't really know how VLA works)

Comment: With questions like this it's typical to link to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) about variable-length arrays such as `int A[N];`. They aren't part of standard C++.

Comment: Tbh I'm amazed that this question pops up over and over again. As if there are multiple primer writers who keep putting it into material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question.

```cpp
int N, i;
```

Here, you declare `N`, but because you don't assign a value to `N`, `N` is uninitialized and can hold any value (probably some old program's value.)
And you create an array with `N`, which will lead to some unexpected behavior. (for example, a stack overflow could happen when `N` is too big)

And:

The size of arrays in C++ has to be known at *compile-time*. That means when you compiler compiles the program, the array's size has to be known.

In your case, you know `n` (the size) at *runtime*, which means only when you run the program, you know the value of `n`, which is the size.

Your code run because (probably) `gcc` compiler does have an extension for this to happen, but because this is not standard C++, I would recommend not using it.

C++ has a solution for runtime array, and that is `std::vector` in the `<vector>` header.

You just need to change:

```cpp
cin >> N;
int A[N];
```

to:

```cpp
std::cin >> n;
std::vector<int> A(N);
```

note: `using namespace std;` is [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), so don't use it.

Answer (score 7):

> Should N have a value before initializing A[N]

Yes. It should. It should even have a value before declaring `A[N]`.
How else would the runtime know how much space to allocate for `A`?

Answer (score 1):

In C++, the size of an array must be a **compile time constant**. So the following code is incorrect:

```
int N = 10;
int arr[N]; //incorrect
```

The correct way to write this would be:

```
const int N = 10;
int arr[N]; //correct
```

For the same reason the following code is **incorrect** in your given code snippet:

```
int N, i; //both N and i are **unitialized**(meaning they have **garbage value**)
cin >> N; //this is fine. This takes input from user and put it in N
int A[N];  //incorrect because N must be a constant expression
```

Also note that your original question used the **garbage value** of N to create an array. This is why it is *advised* that **always initialize built in type in block/local scope.**